# If no Image, change row cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using SDWebImage. I'm pulling the images in correctly from a web service API, but if the API I'm getting the response from doesn't have an image ("null"), I want to realign my Table View Cell.

ViewController.m

```
if ([fL.images count] == 0) {
        //trying to figure out what to put here to change row height
    }
    else {
}
```

WebListCell.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // (X, Y, Width, Height)
    self.publishedLabel.frame = CGRectMake(300, 210, 20, 20); 
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180);
    self.headlineLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 210, 290, 40);
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 250, 290, 30);
    self.premiumLabel.frame = CGRectMake(260, 2, 60, 20);
}
```

My problem is I can't find a good **"if" statement for when there is no image** and I want to realign my Table View Cell.

I think I need to do something in `WeblistCell.m` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for this, but I'm stumped.

Any help would be appreciated!

Will post any necessary code needed!

Comment: I meet the same problem with you, could you tell me how did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are pretty close to the solution for yourself. The key is the method `-heightForRowAtIndexPath:` - this needs to return the different height for the case when the row doesn't have an image. I'm not familiar with SDWebImage but if you are loading images from a web service of some kind, you should know which row (index) an image is for when you try to load it. So, if you go to retrieve an image and there isn't one (null), add that index to a [mutable array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to track missing image. Then your `-heightForRowAtIndexpath:` method just needs to check if the [row property of the indexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) parameter exists in that array.